# Python imports relative path

Tags: python, import, path, relative-path

I've got a project where I would like to use some python classes located in other directories.

Example structure:

```
/dir
 +../subdirA
 +../subdirB
 +../mydir
```

The absolute path varies, because this project is run on different machines.

When my python file with *MySampleClass* located in */mydir* is executed, how do I import *OtherClassRoot* located in */dir* or *OtherClassA* located in */subdirA*?

I tried things like:

```
from . import MySampleClass as msc
```

or

```
from ../ import MySampleClass as msc
```

but this always fails or gives me error messages like *Attempted relative import in non-package*

So, whats the right way to relatively import python files?

Comment: Have you read the section on [Packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in the Python docs? You may also find the example code I posted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26623508/4014959) helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will need an `__init__.py` in the mydir directory (and it can be empty), then as long as dir is in the sys path, assuming your MySampleClass is in myfile.py and myfile.py is in mydir

```
from mydir.myfile import MySampleClass
```

If you want to import top level functions from a file called util.py that reside in subdirA into myfile.py (where your class is), then an `__init__.py` must be in subdirA and then in myfile.py

```
from subdirA.util import somefunc, someotherfunc
```

The same is true of the sys path, that is, you must either start from 'dir' or add it. Everything is imported from the top level of the package (usually your project folder).

However, for module testing, where you might run a function from util in the interpreter, if you start from subdirA, you will need to add dir to the sys path, so your imports can resolve.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('../dir')
```

but this is a hack and would be preferable to only use from the interactive interpreter when you are testing. You can also add 'dir' to your site packages in a pth file.

To use relative imports, you would need a deeper nested folder, like subdirA/subdirofA, then in subdirofA, you could use . to back out (like `from .subdirB` ). Really, for me, relative imports are somewhat difficult to see the utility. It's better for me to use direct imports *relative to the project directory*, but I could see them being useful if you wanted to nest a naive sub package, but again, still better to be explicit than implicit if possible.

also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python?rq=1)

Update for Python 3's [namespace packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages). An `__init__.py` file is no longer required. Some libraries may still reference the file, so it may still be needed for compatibility. For example,

```
(test-env) machine:~ user$ mkdir new_package
(test-env) machine:~ user$ python
>>> import new_package
>>> new_package.__file__
>>> type(new_package.__file__)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
(test-env) machine:~ user$ touch new_package/__init__.py
(test-env) machine:~ user$ python
>>> import new_package
>>> new_package.__file__
'/Users/user/new_package/__init__.py'
>>> type(new_package.__file__)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: I guess you got me wrong (or I explained it bad^^): *MySampleClass* is located in *mydir* and executed. So I want to import some other peoples classes from *subdirA*, *subdirB*, ... into *MySampleClass* (located in *myfile.py* in */mydir*)

Answer (score 2):

first add the relative paths to the pythonpath

```
import os

import sys

cwd = os.getcwd()

sys.path.append(cwd + '/../subdirA/')

sys.path.append(cwd + '/../subdirB/')
```

then import the modules.

Answer (score -2):

On dir structure as following:

```
/dir
 +../subdirA
 +../subdirB
 +../mydir
```

combining with linux command `ln` , we can make things a lot simpler:

```
1. cd dir/mydir
2. ln -s ../subdirA ./
3. ln -s ../subdirB ./
```

And, now if you want to import `some_stuff` from file: `dir/subdirA/fileA.py` into your file: `dir/mydir/myfile.py`, simply import like this:

```
from subdirA.fileA import some_stuff
```

And, the same applies to 'dir/subdirB'

What's More, this works for `setup.py` process, :)

Comment: we all know a lot tricks can be made to get this work around,  eg: `../`, `__init__.py`, they are good but not simple enough,  this is a most maintainable and simple way I found so far,  expecting better and simpler resolutions !