# What does .all mean in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I saw a line in the python code I downloaded:

```
from sth.all import *
```

What does this .all mean? I cannot find any answer related to this.

Comment: `sth` is a package that has an `__init__.py` file, `all` is a module, `*` is everything in that module.

Comment: By the way, just a tip: never use `import *`. Never ever. It makes code totally unreadable. That's not directly related to the question, though -- `from sth.all import foo` would raise the same question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, what is a package? you mean a directory?

Comment: @dannycrane Python package is a directory, yes.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester, thank you for the tip. Do you mean when I call the function, I will not need to specify the file where the function comes from and this may cause confusions?

Comment: When you import *, it's likely that many functions and classes are being imported.  Furthermore, you don't know offhand what the names of all of these are, so they clutter your namespace.  Imagine you import * and it imports a function called "test".  Then later, you import * from another package, and it also has a function "test".  When you go to use test, it will use one and not the other, and this can lead to very hard-to-find errors.

Comment: Danny, see the official Python docs on [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for some info.

Comment: @DashingAdamHughes, Thank you. I just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: @PM2Ring, appreciate the link.

Comment: For sure.  I still use import * way more often than necessary.  Good code usually has a special variable in the files called " __ all__ ", which specifies what can be imported when the user called import *.  In this way, a code might only return a few functions when you do import *, instead of returning 100 functions for a code that lacks the variable.  I guess its a fitting point, since this thread is now about all the all :)  For example https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/filter/rank/__init__.py#L12

Comment: @AndrewGorcester: Certainly `import *` is evil in a normal script, but there are times when it's necessary, typically inside `__init__.py` files. And I guess it can be handy in the interactive interpreter, OTOH, even using it there does encourage bad habits.

Comment: @PM2Ring, why is it necessary to use import * in         __init__.py ?

Comment: @dannycrane: Well, it's not _strictly_ necessary, but it certainly makes things simpler when you're building a package. At this stage of your Python learning you can ignore that stuff, but if you're curious and want to see an example, look at [this demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26623508/4014959) I posted here a few months ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like all is the name of the module.  As in they have a file called all.py in the folder sth