# How can I recursively import every file in a directory and run a function in each one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In essence, I'm trying to make an extension system, where each plugin hooks into the important functions via the respective function in the file. I need a way to run this function and get the return value, by just looping through the "plugins" directory.

Any way I could do this?

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26623508/4014959) helpful, although it is written for Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

you can import files dinamicaly using `__import__`

so you just need to iterate the folder looking for py files (not pyc) and import them

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_path):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.py'):
            m = __import__(f)
```

`m` will now be the instanc of the module , so if you have a function called `my_func` under it, you can do:

`m.my_func()`

or if you have the name of the function as string:

`getattr(m,'my_func')()`

Comment: I actually have 1 issue with this, when I try to run the function, it says "module 'plugins' has no attritube 'function'". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: well it seems python finds your module but not function (did you actually called your function `function`?) try defining other things in your module and see if it can access them , or add some of your code, so i can help you